# Type 'MyType' does not satisfy the constraint 'ObjectShape'. Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'MyType'

Tags: typescript, yup

So, I recently upgraded

- `"yup": "^0.29.1"` => `"yup": "^0.32.11"`
- `"@types/yup": "^0.29.3"` => `"@types/yup": "^0.29.13",`

And now all of my `Schemas` are broken. I'll provide one example, which typescript is crying about:

```js
export interface MyType {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string | null;
}

export const mySchema = yup
  .object<MyType>({
    id: yup.number().required(),
    name: yup.string().trim().required().max(50),
    description: yup.string().trim().max(200).defined(),
  })
  .required();
```

Error from typescript:

```
TS2344: Type 'MyType' does not satisfy the constraint 'ObjectShape'. Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'MyType'.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you gone to the yup project and look if there were any upgrade instructions or BC breaks?

Comment: @Evert I've found something in the change log, saying "`BREAKING CHANGE: plain objects and arrays are no long cast to strings automatically"`, but I doubt that it's related to problem I'm facing

Comment: Looks like a known issue. Fixed in 1.x beta: https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/1510

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work for me

```js
interface MyInterface {
  foo: string;
}

const validationSchema: SchemaOf<MyInterface> = Yup.object().shape({
  foo: Yup.string().required(),
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of specifying the interface to the object, do it to the shape with a Record - `<Record<keyof MyType, yup.AnySchema>>`. So your code would look like this:

```
export const mySchema = yup
  .object().shape<Record<keyof MyType, yup.AnySchema>>({
    id: yup.number().required(),
    name: yup.string().trim().required().max(50),
    description: yup.string().trim().max(200).defined(),
  })
  .required();
```

I haven't found a better solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

I had to set `"strictNullChecks": true`, to get rid of nonsensical type errors. Also, I'm using the most recent beta release rather than the default.

Having that set, this syntax works for me:

```
type MyType = {
  id: string;
};

export const schema: yup.ObjectSchema<MyType> = yup.object({
  id: yup.string().defined(),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while, but I got the working solution. This is working perfectly for me. I hope it helps.

```
interface RowInterface {
    id: number,
    female: string,
    male: string,
    total: number

}

interface GroupInterface {
    code: string;
    description: string;
    rows: RowInterface[];
}


Yup.object().shape < Record < keyof GroupInterface, Yup.AnySchema >> ({
    code: Yup.string(),
    description: Yup.string(),
    rows: Yup.array()
        .of(
            Yup.object().shape({

                id: Yup.number(),
                female: Yup.string(),
                male: Yup.string(),
                total: Yup.number()
            })
        )
        .test(
            'group',
            t('At least one needs to be filled'),
            (rows) => {

                return rows ? false : rows.some(
                    (row) =>
                    Number(row.male) > 0 ||
                    Number(row.female) > 0
                );
            }
        )

})
```